# Doctrine - I'm confused by cascading delete

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony 2 / Doctrine test application, with a number of related tables. The generated CRUD actions are giving confusing results.

First table is a list of countries.

Second table is a list of locations.

Relation is  ( obviously ) :

Country Many to One Location.

I filled the country table with all the countries of the world.

I created a location - 'Amsterdam' related to country 'Netherlands'

So far, operations are working nicely - Symfony / Doctrine create the locationform with the drop-down menu to select the country

Now the problem:
When I deleted the location, the corresponding country record was deleted. This is obviously not the intended behavior.

The countries table should never change, so I can I configure the entities to prevent any cascaded changes ?

```
/**
 * ORM Entity representing country
 *
 * Doctrine2 ORM Entity
 * With lifecycle callbacks to manage timestampable and blameable fields.
 *
 * Used to tie country name to ISO3166 3 character code.
 * Will use same code to name country flags in the interface.
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Newgt\EventBundle\Entity\NewgtCountryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="newgt_country")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 /
class NewgtCountry
{
    /*
     * Database key
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
```

....snip.....

```
/**
 * Country name
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
private $country;
```

....snip....

```
/**
 * Mapping placeholder for NewgtLocation
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewgtLocation", mappedBy="country", cascade={}, orphanRemoval=false)
 */
private $countries;
```

....snip....

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * NewgtLocation Entity
 *
 * Object describing a race location.
 *
 * @uses NewgtCountry::__toString to retrieve the country name
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Newgt\EventBundle\Entity\NewgtLocationRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="newgt_location")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class NewgtLocation
{
    /**
     * Database key
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * Location name
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)
 * @var string
 */
private $name;
```

....snip....

```
/**
 * Country from NewgtCountry table
 * @var \Newgt\EventBundle\Entity\NewgtCountry
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NewgtCountry", cascade={}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $country;
```

....snip....

Steve

EDIT:
Removed all entries from the cascade and it now works.

Comment: Check your mappings.  You have orphan removal enabled somehow.

Comment: I already checked this - both sides have orphanRemoval=false. 
Countries are not children and should not be orphaned.

Comment: Well, if you cascade="all" on the location object then that might do it.

Comment: I already tried cascade={} and orphanRemoval=false

Comment: Hmmm.  Consider updating your question to show the Location-Country relation.  The stuff you have now doesn't help.  Consider also just taking out all the cascade and removal stuff completely.  Then rebuild the database from scratch.

Comment: I updated the code by setting cascade={} and orphanRemoval=false and it is now working. I thought I tried this combination earlier, but now it is working. Thank you for bearing with me.